# Swift (IOS) Update parameter in async function

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, cocoapods

I'm currently working on creating a framework for IOS. My framework has to send request to my server, parse the response and then update the UITableView of the main page of the App.
I've already create a Singleton class "MyUpdater" which has a static func "addRow"
In my Application i have 2 objects: the tableView and a list of objects that i use for the tableView.
I want the "addRow" method (of my FrameWork) to add an object to the object list of the App asynchronously. 
So i created the following method:

```
public static func addRow(tableView: UITableView, list: inout Array<Product>){
var my_object = Object()
list.insert(my_object, at: 1)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.enUpdates()}
```

And i get the following error: escaping closures can only capture inout.

How can i asynchronously update the list of the Application from the pod (framework) ?
Thank you.
Kind regards

Comment: Not related but do not call `reloadData` right after `insertRows`. The insert operation updates the UI and you won't get the animation. And `begin- / endUpdates` has no effect for a single insert/delete/move operation.

Comment: Ok thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `inout` ? I think this makes no sense here, since inout isn't a pass-by-reference.

Did you try something like: ?

```
public func addRow(tableView: UITableView, list: Array<Product>){
   Dispatch.main.async {
      //update the list + tableview
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But when i insert a value into the list, i get an error: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: "products" is a "let" constant